# How do full screen DrawerLayouts affect adding Fragments to the backstack, when setting window SystemUiVisibility to SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme, drawerlayout, android-statusbar

I've encountered a Fragment-related problem in a larger project that I'm working on and I've created a minimal verifiable example to explain it:

### The example setup:

The example project is an app with no action bar (the theme has `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as its parent), with `targetSdkVersion 27` and `minSdkVersion 23`.

The main activity is an `AppCompatActivity` with an `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` as its root layout. This DrawerLayout has `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`, to overlap the status bar.

Inside the `DrawerLayout`, there is a `FrameLayout` that will host an `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. The fragment is added to the interface and to the backstack when a button is tapped:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContent, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

This fragment shows a button that removes the fragment by calling `onBackPressed` on the activity.

So far, the app's behavior is normal: the fragment is added when tapping the button on the activity layout and then it's removed when tapping the button on the fragment layout.

### The problem:

I add a new button to the activity, that when tapped, sets the status bar color to white and the `SystemUiVisibility` for the window decor view, to `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`:

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.white));
window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
```

After tapping this button, the status bar is, as expected, shown with black text on a white background.

The unexpected part is that **after this change, the fragment is no longer shown on the interface when I tap the button that adds it**.

The fragment still appears to be placed on the backstack, since pressing the system back key doesn't immediately finish the activity, removing the fragment instead. I've confirmed this by adding log statements in the fragment's `onResume` and `onPause` methods and seeing that they are called when the fragment is added and removed from the backstack.

### The investigation:

I've tried multiple workarounds and I've explored a number of possible causes.

What I've managed to find:

- The problem only occurs for some app configurations. All of these should be true for the problem to manifest itself:

  1. The app theme has `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as its parent.
  2. The activity has `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` as its root layout.
  3. The `DrawerLayout` has `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`.
  4. Both the status bar color and the `SystemUiVisibility` for the window decor view must be set.
  5. The `SystemUiVisibility` for the window decor view must be set to `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`.

  These may seem arbitrary, but I need them in my app to have the interface show no action bar, provide a full-screen side menu and adapt the color of the status bar to the color of each layout I'm showing.

- I've looked into the code for `DrawerLayout`, as a possible source of insights into the matter. I've even created a local copy of the component, so I could comment out various sections and add log statements to trace the behavior.

  I've managed to track down the problem to `DrawerLayout` setting its `SystemUiVisibility` to `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN`.

  When these flags are set, the `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener` gets called when I set the status bar color to white and the `SystemUiVisibility` for the window decor view to `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`.

  In turn, this listener calls a `setChildInsets` method, that calls `requestLayout()` on the `DrawerLayout`, at the end.

  This layout request is the last received by the `DrawerLayout`. From this point onward, its `onLayout` method no longer gets called when setting the status bar color and the `SystemUiVisibility` for the window decor view, nor when adding a fragment. Nor the `onMeasure` method or the `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener` ever get called after this point. Fragment views are no longer shown and logging their size reveals that it stays 0.

### The code:

You can [download the example project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XfyfNUTqJUlO8QPKrLC-6Sl4Y1ud8Ee_).

### The question(s):

What causes this, how and why? Does it have anything to do with `DrawerLayout` directly, or is its behavior only a consequence triggered by something else?

Why does this happen only when the app has no action bar and when `SystemUiVisibility` for the window decor view is set only to `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to replicate the issue you have described using your example project. I can show and remove the fragment regardless of whether I toggle the status bar color or not.

It's also possible that the reason it's causing bugs is that you are not applying/removing the other flags mentioned in the [documentation of `setStatusBarColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor(int)). Try this:

```
// clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

// add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

// finally change the color
window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.my_statusbar_color));
```

Funnily enough, I **was** able to replicate the issue you described after trying out the code above, which makes it even more confusing.

I will therefore recommend an alternative approach - use a CoordinatorLayout instead of the Window for drawing the status bar color. Make the CoordinatorLayout a direct child of the DrawerLayout, and add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to it. Then instead of calling `window.setStatusBarColor()`, call `coordinatorLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor()`. This solution does not require any special window flags, but note that for this to work you also need to add the following line to your Theme:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

I am also using a CoordinatorLayout in a large project for dynamically changing the color of the status bar, so hopefully it will work for you as well. It definitely works in the example project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did find workarounds myself, by rearranging the layouts in a number of ways. However, the question is one of root cause analysis: what causes the problem and why does it happen only in such very specific circumstances. I'm sensing that the answer would have to refer to the source code of some of the Android components involved and demonstrate how certain implementation details lead up to this behavior.